# Can you have number of followers split on date through Instagram API?

Tags: database, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I have made an app, that is extracting data through the Instagram API. I have used the Get request:  GET/users/self to get an overview of the number of followers on the page i am requesting data for. 
What struck me is, that it seems there is no endpoint supporting getting this information on a date basis? 
Is this correct? Cant you know how many followers the profile had on a specific date?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Through the API, the answer is NO.

If the Instagram account is a Business Instagram Account linked to Facebook, you can use the Facebook Insight endpoint to get the evolution of the number of followers.